# how to return the latest 2 dates using self-joint in mysql

Tags: mysql, self-join

I want to retrieve the latest 2 degree that each person received. The original table store information like below:

```
personnel_num | certificate_txt | degree_date
------------------------------------------------------
10000   Bachelor Degree - Science   1979-06-06
10000   Master Degree - Business    1982-12-31
10001   Bachelor Degree - Arts      1991-05-01
10001   Master Degree - Business    1995-12-01
10001   Bachelor Degree - Science   1974-06-01
10002   Master Degree - Arts        1981-03-01
10003   Doctor Of Law               1978-05-01
10003   Master Degree - Science     1981-05-01
10006   Bachelor Degree - Science   1996-06-01
10006   Master Degree - Business    2004-05-01
10007   Bachelor Degree - Business  2002-05-01
```

I tried with the following script:

```
select tb1.personnel_num, tb1.certificate_txt, tb1.degree_date
from education tb1
left join education tb2
on tb1.personnel_num = tb2.personnel_num
and tb1.degree_date > tb2.degree_date
group by personnel_num
having count(*) <= 2
order by personnel_num;
```

and I am running into two problems:
1. The results give me the latest degree each person has rather than latest 2 degrees.
2. Anyone has more than 2 degrees in the original table is not being returned. I think that has to do with `having count(*) <=2` but that should be controlling the returned result not the original table.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The concept is wrong.

1. `GROUP BY personnel_num` ensures that you will have at most 1 result record for each personnel_num. In that record you select only 1 date so you cannot possibly expect to get 2 dates per personnel.
2. `HAVING COUNT(*)<=2` says that only those groups are considered which are aggregated of at most 2 records. But you did a join (all rows to all rows) where newer-older pairs are valid. When you have 4 records with values of 2007,2008,2009,2010 then the pairs (tb1.degree_date to tb2.degree_date) in the joined result will be: 2010-2009, 2010-2008, 2010-2007, 2009-2008, 2009-2007, 2008-2007; thats 6 records (much more than 2).
3. So to rectify both the above, we need 1. to select both dates, and 2. to aggregate them to their respective maximums and drop the HAVING.

   ```
   SELECT tb1.personnel_num, MAX(tb1.degree_date), MAX(tb2.degree_date)
   FROM education tb1
   LEFT JOIN education tb2
   ON tb1.personnel_num = tb2.personnel_num AND tb1.degree_date > tb2.degree_date
   GROUP BY personnel_num
   ORDER BY personnel_num;
   ```

Hint: Provide an SQLfiddle for your original SQL question, so you will be likely to get more accurate answers faster.

Comment: Thanks Levente, how can I melt the data into long format such as this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/935cf/2/0

Comment: Also, this one is telling sql that I want 2 degree date, but it will become tedious if I need 3 or 4 or 5. That is why I thought `having count(*)` will take care of it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Whoa, the latter is a completely different matter, and partly depends on whether there may be equal values: is it legal if someone got two degrees at the same date?

Comment: `SELECT tb1.personnel_num, tb1.degree_date, concat(tb1.personnel_num, tb1.degree_date) as uniqueid FROM education tb1 LEFT JOIN education tb2 ON tb1.personnel_num = tb2.personnel_num AND tb1.degree_date > tb2.degree_date group by uniqueid having count(*) < 2 order by personnel_num;` works